# BlockingGet block UI thread RxJava 2

Tags: android, multithreading, rx-java, rx-java2

I am dealing with the problem.

I am trying to call RxJava in the sync manner, however doing that results in blocking the Main thread.

Here is my code

```
   @Override
    public Single<SettingsBundle> getSettings() {
        SettingsBundle settingsModel = mSettingsManager.getSettings();
        return Single.just(settingsModel).map(mSettingsMapper);
    }
```

And here is my sync call

```
   @Override
    public SettingsBundle getSettingsSync() {
        return getSettings().blockingGet();
    }
```

When calling the `getSettingsSync` the Main thread is blocked, however sometimes it works fine, what is more problematic.

I have tried something like that

```
@Override
public SettingsBundle getSettingsSync() {
    return getSettings()
            .subscribeOn(Schedulers.newThread())
            .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
            .blockingGet();
}
```

But it stills remains blocked.

What I am doing wrong, I would be grateful for any help.

Thanks.

Comment: A blocking all will block until there's data.  Do not use one on the UI thread.  Either have another thread do it, or use a non-blocking call.

Comment: What is your problem exactly? The `blockingGet()` call will block the _current_ thread until the data is available, this is the expected behavior. What do you want to achieve?

Comment: @GergelyKőrössy , it doesn't get released causing my thread to stuck

Comment: If you don't want to block the UI thread, then don't use `blockingGet` which has "blocking" in its name

Answer (score 20):

**TL;TR**

never use `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` with `blockingGet()`

---

**Long version**

The output for:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

        val result =
                Single.just("Hello")
                .subscribeOn(Schedulers.io())
               // .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                .map {
                    println("1. blockingGet `$it` thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
                    return@map it
                }
                .blockingGet()
        println("2. blockingGet `$result` thread: ${Thread.currentThread()}")
    }
}
```

is

```
 1. blockingGet `Hello` thread: Thread[RxCachedThreadScheduler-1,5,main]
 2. blockingGet `Hello` thread: Thread[main,5,main]
```

As you can see result was generated on main thread (line 2), the map function was execute in the RxCachedThreadScheduler thread.

With the line `.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` decommented the `blockingGet()` never return and all is stucked.

Comment: Isn't that while "result" in onCreate is waiting to be initialized by the result of this single, the main thread is blocked?

Answer (score 5):

```
.observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
.blockingGet();
```

The problem exists in this specific combination of operators. AndroidSchedulers schedules code to run on the main thread, however the `blockingGet()` stops more code from executing on that thread. Simply put `AndroidSchedulers` and the blocking operators of `RxJava` do not work well together.

Since the android scheduler might be used in the construction of the observable this means any use of the `blocking*` operators on the main thread will be prone to deadlocks regardless of what you try to do.

Answer (score 0):

If you really need a function to run on the main thread and also need it to be synchronous, then you could do something like this:

1. If this is the main thread (`Looper.myLooper() == Looper.getMainLooper()`), then run func()
2. If not on the main thread, then you can use the combination of   `observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())` with `blockingGet()`