# Convert Single<Boolean> to Boolean (Kotlin)

Tags: android, mvvm, kotlin, rx-java, rx-java2

I have a mutable live data which I use to adjust visibility(with binding adapter) in my layout. I use the boolean value of live data to achieve this with the code below.

```
@BindingAdapter("viewVisibility")
fun setVisibility(view: View, visible: Boolean) {
    view.visibility = if (visible) View.VISIBLE else View.GONE
}
```

To get this data I use the following method

```
   Flowable.just(
Sdk().searchContact(CHATBOT_NAME)).map {!(it.isEmpty()) }
```

it.isEmpty() gives me a Flowable < Single< Boolean>> instead of Flowable and I want to convert this Single to a boolean(to give it as a parameter to my binding adapter) but I could not find a way to convert it. My temporary (probably bad) solution is below.

```
  it.blockingLast().isEmpty() // Blocking last gives me a list so I can get non-single boolean with isEmpty. Since I need one element from search contact method blocking last or first works same in this case.
```

Is this an acceptable solution? How can I convert Single to normal Boolean?

Comment: ` gives me a Flowable> instead of Flowable`  - what do you mean by that?

Comment: Seems stackoverFlow deletes the part after "<" . Fixed it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it's me again,try following code:

```
fun doesExist(): Flowable<Boolean> {
   return Flowable.just(Single.just(Sdk().searchContact(CHATBOT_NAME)).map{ it.isEmpty()}).map {it.blockingGet() }
}
```

Comment: I am going to try this in an hour. By the way, what is the purpose of additional Single.just after Flowable.just? I think it is unnecessary as method still returns Single without it. Do single.just and flowable.just have different behavior?

Comment: Because you want Single<Boolean> before last questionn,if you don't need that,then delete Single.just and code will be Flowable.just(ArrayList<String>()).map{ it.isEmpty()}

Comment: Accepted. Side note : Seems like using blocking get with Androidschedulers cause problems . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46614494/blockingget-block-ui-thread-rxjava-2

Comment: Yes,if your operation is consuming time then you shouldn't do it in your Main thread ,you can use Schedulers.io() instead of Androidschedulers.main