# Rx java2 - blockingGet() inside AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()

Tags: android, mvvm, rx-java2

Helllo,

getInfo() service call is subscribed by several fragments same time, so I want to call service only once, store that info and return it.

I found solution by using blockingGet()

```
 addDisposable(getInfoUseCase().get()
                        .observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread())
                        .subscribe(info -> {}
                                , throwable -> {}));
```

which finally translates to this:

```
    private var info: InfoEntity? = null
    
        override fun getInfo(): Single<InfoEntity> {
            return if (info== null) {
            Single.just(service.getInfo(SERVICE_GET_INFO).blockingGet())
                .map { mapper.transform(it) }
                .doOnSuccess {
                    info = it
                }
        } else {
            return Single.just(info)
        }
    }
```

And here is service object:

```
   Retrofit restAdapter = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                .client(createClient(TIMEOUT, true))
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .addCallAdapterFactory(RxJava2CallAdapterFactory.createWithScheduler(Schedulers.io()))
                .build();

        service = restAdapter.create(RetrofitService.class);


@GET(".")
    Single<ApiResponse<InfoEntity>> getInfo(
            @Query(SERVICE_ID) String serviceId
    );
```

At first glance, everything works fine, but then I found this answer:

[never use observeOn(AndroidSchedulers.mainThread()) with blockingGet()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48102818/2183441)

but in my case everything works fine, I don't get whats the difference, is there any problem with my approach? If so, whats way out from it?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are blocking the main thread. That means while you are waiting for the network call (which could take 5 seconds) the UI will be completely frozen and the user won't be able to do anything. This is really not a great UX.

The fix is tricky. A `BehaviorSubject` is useful here because it allows all fragments that subscribe while the network call is fetching to receive the notification of a result.

```
// I assume these variables are in a singleton? Otherwise they won't be much use
private var subject: BehaviorSubject<InfoEntity> = BehaviorSubject.create()
var isFetching = false

override fun getInfo(): Single<InfoEntity> {

    // If the network call previously failed, reset the subject to a new empty one, so that this subscriber and future ones can receive a value
    if (subject.hasThrowable() || subject.hasComplete()) {
        subject = BehaviorSubject.create()
    }

    if (!subject.hasValue() && !isFetching) {
        isFetching = true
        fetch()
    }

    return subject.firstOrError()
}

private fun fetch() {
    fetchInfo()
            .doFinally {
                isFetching = false
            }
            .subscribe(
                    {
                        subject.onNext(it)
                    }, {
                        subject.onError(it)
                    })
}
```

Comment: in your example, several calls will be make if several fragments subscribe at same time, cause before first one downloads info, second one will subscribe and do network call, I want only one network call, thats why i used blockingGet...

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll fix that for you. What you might want is a BehaviourSubject

Comment: Hmm this makes it harder and you have to consider a few things. What do you want to happen if the first network call fails? Provide the error to all fragments? Retry whenever a new fragment subscribes?

Comment: providing error to fragments, works fine for me, and yeah, after error is provided, if new subscription comes, retry would be nesccecery :D